# Get which points are included in heat map's zones

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, visualization, heatmap

I've been trying to recreate this particular plot

[image]

From the events' positions, I can plot the heat map with `histogram2d` like this. The white points are the start of events

[image]

```
xbins = np.linspace(-35, 35, 11)
ybins = np.linspace(0, 105, 22)
# all_x and all_y is arrays of all starting x points and starting y points of all events
heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(all_x, all_y, bins=(xbins,ybins))
extent = [-35, 35, 0, 105]
ax.imshow(heatmap.T, extent=extent, origin='lower')
```

But I don't know which points are from a specific 'zone' of the heat map. So I can't calculate the average length and direction of those events which start from those points.

How can I get those points ? Or am I doing wrong since even if I know the starting points, I have to look further to get the "finish points", to get the direction and length, and only after that, I get the average direction and length.

Sorry for my bad English.